# How to avoid onbeforeunload preventing Watir test from exiting

Tags: watir, onbeforeunload

I have a webpage that uses onbeforeunload to prompt the user for confirmation whenever they try and navigate away from the page. This confirmation even fires when the browser window is closed.

My problem is that this prompt is preventing Watir from closing IE at the end of a test run, at least until I manually intervene and click "OK".

How can I write my tests such that Watir automatically dismisses this prompt, even if the test fails? I'm thinking there might be some conditional logic in the test teardown method, but I need help interacting with the popup.

**Note**: I have a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758699/how-to-click-on-onbeforeunload-prompt-in-watir-test) pertaining to interacting with the onbeforeunload prompt when it is created by a click event. This question is about handling that popup when it is created by a request to close the window.

Comment: Watir community here is small, you should also post this to http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll do that!

Comment: There's an open bug (feature request) for a method to deal with this in watir-webdriver.  You can comment or upvote it here https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/109

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really need to test that dialog, you can overwrite onbeforeunload.

Not sure how it can be done in Watir, but in Watir-WebDriver it'll look like

```
browser.execute_script "window.onbeforeunload = null"
```