# How to click on onbeforeunload prompt in Watir test?

Tags: watir, onbeforeunload

I have a webpage that has an onbeforeunload script that prompts the user when they take an action that would navigate away from the current page.

How do I interact with this popup using Watir? My current approach looks like this:

```
$ie.link(:text, 'Dashboard').click_no_wait

hwnd = $ie.enabled_popup(10)
assert(hwnd, 'The expected \'leave this page?\' popup was not shown')

win = WinClicker.new
win.makeWindowActive(hwnd)
win.clickWindowsButton_hwnd(hwnd, "OK")
```

The problem is that if I use "click no wait" the popup is not created, and the test times out. If I use "click" then the popup is created, but the test hangs after it opens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Watir community here is small, you should also post this to http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to assert dialog message?
I try your code, but could not find solution.
This is to try to catch dialog then when popup,get msg while 5sec. polling per 1sec.

```
$ie.link(:text, 'Dashboard').click_no_wait
@autoit = WIN32OLE.new('AutoItX3.Control')
  5.times do
    if @autoit.WinWait('Windows Internet Explorer','',1)==1 then
      @autoit.WinActivate('Windows Internet Explorer',"")
      @dialog_text = @autoit.WinGetText('Windows Internet Explorer',"")
      dialog_pop = "YES"
      break
    else
      sleep(1)
      dialog_pop = "NO"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick closing this alert:

```
browser.alert.ok
```

See the [Watir docs here](http://watir.com/guides/alerts/).